# Help Identifying Vent Purpose

Tags: exhaust-vent, venting

I'm trying to figure out what a vent on my roof is for. I have two vents close together. #2 in the photo is for the venting of the hot water heater. #1 is the one I'm not sure about. It has an insulated wire zip tied to the outside of it, runs along the wall then disappears inside the wall. #2 is exhausted above the roof, while #1 just vents into a crawl space inside the home.

Could someone infom me as to the function of this vent and the wire?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Not sure enough to call it an answer - make-up air for the water heater, especially if it's a well-sealed house (or room) where the water heater is located?

Comment: Finally, on top of your heater, do you have 2 water lines running into the water heater from the top?  One should be cold inlet, and the other the hot output.  I'm concerned about the one coming out the side - where does that one go?  That T&P valve (in my understanding and experience) should run down the side of the water heater and drain into a visible location.  It looks like it could actually be either the hot or cold supply to the heater, which is a big no-no with no way to allow the T&P valve to work properly.

Comment: Could be a provision for radon mitigation.

Comment: @Milwrdfan The copper line attached to the TPRV likely just empties outside.  All the houses in my neighborhood are plumbed like that - there is a 90 degree turndown on the nearest exterior wall.

Comment: @Milwrdfan yes, it is in its own room off the garage.

Comment: It appears that the bottom of pipe #1 is capped in some way. Is that a solid cap or is it open?

Comment: @FreeMan it is open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may just extend into the vented attic to supply combustion air to the burner of the water heater. Some plumbers opine it is a code requirement to have a tube extend down to the level of the burner. Others think a wire mesh panel in the ceiling is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Not uncommon in well insulate houses for gas fired water heater.   However this looks like might be an electric heater.  The screen comment is correct.